# Combining two dataframe rows into one

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a dataframe, `df`, with 3 columns: `name`, `salary`, and `position`.

I am trying to create a new dataframe containing all possible combinations of any two rows, which I have partially achieved using:

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

cc = list(combinations(df.index,2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[c,['name','salary','position']] for c in cc], index=cc)
```

I would like this code to createa new dataframe (`df2`) with six columns `name1`, `name2`, `salary1`, `salary2`, `position1`, and `position2`. Each column would include their respective row's data - for instance, `name1` would contain the value in `name` for the first of the two rows being combined, and `name2` would contain the value in `name` for the second of the two rows.

Currently, the code produces three columns(`name`, `salary`, and `position`), joining the strings from the original dataframe together. For example, the first row's `name` value is 'JohnSmithJaneDoe'. As all entries are of different length, I cannot simply slice them into two new columns.

EDIT:

My data is:

```
name = ['Barnes', 'Davies', 'Fernandes', 'Freeman', 'Gomes', 'Gray', 'Henderson', 'James', 'Jota', 'Kelly', 'Long', 'McCarthy', 'Pereira', 'Ward', 'Smith']
salary = [51, 48, 52, 69, 46, 83, 123, 78, 71, 63, 61, 48, 65, 49, 62]
position = ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '0', '3', '1', '3']

pd.DataFrame({'name':name,'salary':salary,'position':position})
```

Comment: can you post your data

Comment: Data has been added

Comment: can you also add some expected outputs. If I am not wrong you want `df2['name1'][0]="Barnes Davies` and `df2['name2'][0]="Davies` ? what happens in salary and position ? The columns might be on unequal lengths, do you use `None` for the rest of the values ?

Comment: Expected output for row 1 would be:
name1="Barnes"
name2="Davies"
salary1=51
salary2=48
position1='0'
position2='1'

Comment: your data has odd number of values. what happens to name2, salary2 and position2 in case of last row ? are they none ? or does you second row have name1 as Davies ?

Comment: itertools.combinations only gives every single possible pair, not leaving any left over. With this data, there will be 105 possible combinations of length 2 (itertools.combinations(range(15),2)).

Comment: i might not be understanding your question well. can you please give a few more rows of your expected output ?

Comment: Sure. If you run itertools.combinations(range(15,2)), you will get a list of 105 tuples, each containing 2 elements, such as (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), the last one being (13,14). My expected output is a dataframe of length 105, in which each row combines the rows from the original dataframe indicated by each tuple. For instance, row 2 in the new dataframe would be a combination of row 0 and row 2 in the old (`name1:"Barnes", name2:"Fernandes", salary1:51, salary2:52, position1:0, position2:1`). Row 3 would be `name1:"Barnes", name2:"Freeman", salary1:51, salary2:69, position1:0, position2:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
name = ['Barnes', 'Davies', 'Fernandes', 'Freeman', 'Gomes', 'Gray', 'Henderson', 'James', 'Jota', 'Kelly', 'Long', 'McCarthy', 'Pereira', 'Ward', 'Smith']
salary = [51, 48, 52, 69, 46, 83, 123, 78, 71, 63, 61, 48, 65, 49, 62]
position = ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '0', '3', '1', '3']

df=pd.DataFrame({'name':name,'salary':salary,'position':position})
cc=list(combinations(df.index,2))
## create empty df2
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['name1','name2','salary1','salary2','position1','position2'])
## generate rows by combination in cc
for ind,i in enumerate(cc):
    l1=df.loc[i[0]]
    l2=df.loc[i[1]]
    temp=[l1['name'],l2['name'],l1['salary'],l2['salary'],l1['position'],l2['position']]
    df2.loc[ind] = temp

print(df2)
```

Gives a data frame something like this(the spacing gets distorted due to copying from jupyter notebook):

```py
    name1   name2   salary1 salary2 position1   position2
0   Barnes  Davies  51      48      0           1
1   Barnes  Fernandes   51  52      0           1
2   Barnes  Freeman 51      69      0           1
3   Barnes  Gomes   51      46      0           1
4   Barnes  Gray    51      83      0           2
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
100 McCarthy    Ward    48  49      0           1
101 McCarthy    Smith   48  62      0           3
102 Pereira Ward    65      49      3           1
103 Pereira Smith   65      62      3           3
104 Ward    Smith   49      62      1           3
```

Comment: Wow. A simple and efficient answer to something that had me stumped for hours. Thank you!